# No puedo ir de una pagina a otra con Link router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Tengo un proyecto en react JS y estoy usando react router para las rutas.La primer pagina muestra un listado de items, y al dar click a cualquiera de ellos debe enviarme a otra pagina. El problema es que no cambia de página, no muestra error alguno pero no hace nada, pero en la url si se ve reflejado el cambio.

Router.js

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {HashRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../components/App.js';
import Pokemon from '../components/Pokemon.js';

class Routes extends Component{
render(){
    return (
    <Router>  
      <Switch>           
         <Route exact path="/" component={App} />      
         <Route exact path="/pokemon/:id" component={Pokemon} />       
     </Switch>
    </Router>
    )
   }
}
export default Routes
```

App

```html
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <div className="container">
        <Dashboard />
      </div>     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard

```html
class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                <Index />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Index

```html
class Index extends Component {
    state={
        url:"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/",
        pokemon:null
    };

    async componentDidMount(){
        const res= await axios.get(this.state.url);
        this.setState({ pokemon: res.data['results'] });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
            {this.state.pokemon? (
                <div className="row">
                {this.state.pokemon.map(pokemon=>(
                    <Card 
                    key={pokemon.name}
                    name={pokemon.name}
                    url={pokemon.url}/>
                ))
                }
              </div>
            ) : 
            (
                <h1>Cargando pokemones</h1>
            )}
           </>
        );
    }
}

export default Index;
```

Card

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {HashRouter as Router, Link,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class Card extends Component { 
state={
    name:'',
    imgUrl:'',
    id:'',
    types:[],
}

const history = useHistory();

async componentDidMount(){
    const {name,url}=this.props;    
    const id=url.split("/")[url.split("/").length-2];
    const imgUrl=`https://github.com/PokeApi/sprites/blob/master/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png?raw=true`;
    this.setState({
        name,
        imgUrl,
        id,
        types:[],
    })

    //url for pokemon information
    const pokemonUrl=`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${id}/`;
     
    //get pokemon information
    const response=await axios.get(pokemonUrl); 
    console.log(response);      
    this.setState({        
        types:response.data.types.map(type=>type.type.name),
    })    
    
     
}
render() {
    return (
            <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-5 mt-5">
         {/*   <Router>             
            <Link to={`/pokemon/${this.state.id}`}> */}
                <Card className="card align-items-center"  onClick={() => history.push(`/pokemon/${this.state.id}`)}>
                    <h6 className="m-3" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
                    {this.state.name
                           .toLowerCase()
                           .split(' ')
                           .map(
                               l=> l.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + l.substring(1)
                               )
                           .join(' ')}                           
                    </h6>
                    <h6>{this.state.id}</h6>
                    {
                        this.state.imageLoading?(
                            <img src=".\.\image\spinner.png" style={{width:'6em', height:'6em'}} 
                            className="card-img-top rounded mx-auto mt-0"></img>
                        )
                        :null
                    }

                    <Sprite className="card-img-top rounded mx-auto mt-2"
                    onLoad={()=>this.setState({imageLoading:false})}
                    onError={()=>this.setState({toManyRequests:true})}
                    src={this.state.imgUrl} 
                    style={
                        this.state.toManyRequests?{display:'none'}:
                        this.state.imageLoading? null : {display:'block'}
                    }                      
                    />
                    {this.state.toManyRequests ? (
                        <h6 className="mx-auto">
                            <span className="badge badge-danger mt-2">Muchas peticiones</span>
                        </h6>
                    ):null}
                   <div className="card-body">                       
                    <h6 className="card-tittle">

                    {this.state.types &&  
                    <>
                    {this.state.types.map(type=>(
                    <span key={type}
                    className="badge badge-primary badge-pill mr-1 pt-1 p-2"
                    style={{backgroundColor: `#${TYPE_COLORS[type]}`, color:'white'}}>
                    {type}                            
                    </span>
                    ))  
                    }
                    </> 
                    }                    
                            
                    </h6>
                   </div>
                </Card>
          {/*   </Link>         
            </Router> */}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu raiz es "#"?
**intenta usar history de router dom**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
```

**en tu elemento click**

```
 onClick={() => useHistory().push(`/pokemon/${miId}`)}
```

***tu caso debes convertir tu clase en un componente de funcion***

```
 import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router';
const Card = ({name,url}) => {
    const id=url.split("/")[url.split("/").length-2];
    const imgUrl=`https://github.com/PokeApi/sprites/blob/master/sprites/pokemon/${id}.png?raw=true`;

    return (  <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mb-5 mt-5">
    {/*   <Router>             
       <Link to={`/pokemon/${this.state.id}`}> */}
           <Card className="card align-items-center"  onClick={() => useHistory().push(`/pokemon/${this.state.id}`)}>
               <h6 className="m-3" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
               {this.state.name
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .split(' ')
                      .map(
                          l=> l.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + l.substring(1)
                          )
                      .join(' ')}                           
               </h6>
               <h6>{this.state.id}</h6>
               {
                   this.state.imageLoading?(
                       <img src=".\.\image\spinner.png" style={{width:'6em', height:'6em'}} 
                       className="card-img-top rounded mx-auto mt-0"></img>
                   )
                   :null
               }

               <Sprite className="card-img-top rounded mx-auto mt-2"
               onLoad={()=>this.setState({imageLoading:false})}
               onError={()=>this.setState({toManyRequests:true})}
               src={this.state.imgUrl} 
               style={
                   this.state.toManyRequests?{display:'none'}:
                   this.state.imageLoading? null : {display:'block'}
               }                      
               />
               {this.state.toManyRequests ? (
                   <h6 className="mx-auto">
                       <span className="badge badge-danger mt-2">Muchas peticiones</span>
                   </h6>
               ):null}
              <div className="card-body">                       
               <h6 className="card-tittle">

               {this.state.types &&  
               <>
               {this.state.types.map(type=>(
               <span key={type}
               className="badge badge-primary badge-pill mr-1 pt-1 p-2"
               style={{backgroundColor: `#${TYPE_COLORS[type]}`, color:'white'}}>
               {type}                            
               </span>
               ))  
               }
               </> 
               }                    
                       
               </h6>
              </div>
           </Card>
     {/*   </Link>         
       </Router> */}
       </div> );
}
 

export default Card;
```

Comment: lo he añadido y ahora me manda esto: React Hook "useHistory" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Comment: pont esto const history = useHistory();   y usalo asi   onClick={() => history.push(`/pokemon/${miId}`)}

Comment: ahora me dice esto Unexpected use of 'history'

Comment: puedes compartir tu clase completa? history es una simple variable, ya te actualice como se veria en tu caso

Comment: he editado la pregunta, asi como declaras history  marca error

Comment: muestra tu codigo

Comment: ya actualicé la clase Card

Comment: actualice tu caso

Comment: lo he editado y ahora me manda esto al darle click Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: que version de router dom usas

Comment: "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",

Comment: para poder usarlo debes tener un componente de funcion y no uno de clase, ya te agrego un ejemplo